# Capturing full resolution still image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to capture a still image from a Surface Book Pro with Python. Grabbing a frame from a videostream (with OpenCV or similar) is no problem. However, the resolution is restricted to 1920x1080 due to the camera using the 'video mode'.

I would like to capture a full resolution image at 8MP. So far, I have only found one example, which might be able to do that ( [Camera Capture with Python and DirectShow](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1274094/Capturing-Images-from-Camera-using-Python-and-Dire) ), but it lacks the 'StillImage'-Pin necessary to do so. It probably would be possible to add the PinMode to it, however, Microsoft seems to go away from DirectShow to Media Foundation, so I do not know how long that solution might be viable.

Is there any other possibility to trigger the 'Camera mode' of the integrated camera, to obtain a full resolution image?